# Best way to use two language in a website

Tags: php, sql, database, translation

What is the best way to use 2 language in a website while data are taken from **Database**

> What I searched for

I have found a Google Translate Plugin but actually I don't like google translate translation plus I have to add google banner.

> Problem

I can make the website with two languages but the problem is that it is a dynamic website that users will enter data in English in database and I want to output it in two languages.

Comment: yes if everything is utf 8

Comment: Do you use any of the php open sources like laravel, WordPress?

Comment: Vote to close the question as OP is unclear about what he is asking

Comment: @manian yes I am using Laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are doing your project with spring mvc then you can easily do localization.

Comment: but the problem is localization I have to translate everything by myself?

Comment: There is no auto translate service that provides proper translations. If you're OK with "probably understandable" translations then just add the Google translations thing.

Comment: You can always write a language translate module.  It's a lot of work, but you get to define what is being displayed